# Yii2 The requested page does not exist **Not Found (#404)**

Tags: yii2

I'm new to Yii2,

here is the website [almousa.net](http://almousa.net/)
the issue here that I can not go to the [backend](http://almousa.net/backend), I always get The requested page does not exist and the page title Not Found (#404)

I tried everything from changing the .htaccess to changing the url
how can I solve that?
I noticed that there are no index.php in the website base folder and as if all the requests are going to the front end
[image: website base folder]

Comment: It depend's on your vhosts and domain configuration. It can be `domain.com/admin`, `domain.com/backend`, `domain.com/asdasdasd`, `admin.domain.com`, `secondarydomain.com` etc.

Comment: I recently moved the website from hosting to another one

Comment: So my answer is the same.

Comment: I'm agree with @yupik . In my test for yii2 advance app, for example, i use localhost.com/backend/web/index.php

Comment: you are correct but now I have another problem, 
GET http://admin.almousa.net/backend/assets/adfa53a6/js/AdminLTE/app.js 404 (Not Found)
GET http://backend.almousa.net/backend/assets/adfa53a6/js/AdminLTE/app.js 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I have installed a fresh copy of Yii2 advanced and following standard steps I got everything OK. But the same problem like you mentioned here that the backend was not working.For this I added an additional .htaccess file inside backend folder(/backend) with the following code:

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
# Deny accessing below extensions
<Files ~ "(.json|.lock|.git)">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
# Deny accessing dot files
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
```

Please do follow and I hope it helps.Your config settings must be correct in addition to 1 more .htaccess inside backend/web folder with the following code:

```
    RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: there are some kind or redirection 
http://backend.almousa.net
it goes to: 
http://backend.almousa.net/backend/home/almousanet/public_html/almousa.net/almousa.net/frontend/web/backend

Comment: I tried this one `Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# if request dosn't start with web add it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(web)
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1

# if file or directory dosn't exists go to /web/index.php 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /web/index.php ` it solved the redirection but now I have 404 page not found for the asset

Comment: Ok that's good. Try to clear the cached assets i.e. you can rename the assets folder inside the backend/web/ folder and make a new assets folder and copy the .gitignore file from old assets to new one.Try removing browser cache and then check if it helps.